# HTML localStorage setItem and getItem performance near 5MB limit?

Tags: html, webkit, local-storage, gecko

I was building out a little project that made use of HTML localStorage. While I was nowhere close to the 5MB limit for localStorage, I decided to do a stress test anyway.

Essentially, I loaded up data objects into a single localStorage Object until it was just slightly under that limit and must requests to set and get various items.

I then timed the execution of setItem and getItem informally [using the javascript Date object](http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/) and event handlers (bound get and set to buttons in HTML and just clicked =P)

The performance was horrendous, with requests taking between 600ms to 5,000ms, and memory usage coming close to 200mb in the worser of the cases. This was in Google Chrome with a single extension (Google Speed Tracer), on MacOSX.

In Safari, it's basically >4,000ms all the time.

Firefox was a surprise, having pretty much nothing over 150ms.

These were all done with basically an idle state - No YouTube (Flash) getting in the way, not many tabs (nothing but Gmail), and with no applications open other than background process + the Browser. Once a memory-intensive task popped up, localStorage slowed down proportionately as well. FWIW, I'm running a late 2008 Mac -> 2.0Ghz Duo Core with 2GB DDR3 RAM.

===

So the questions:

1. Has anyone done a benchmarking of sorts against localStorage get and set for various different key and value sizes, and on different browsers?
2. I'm assuming the large variance in latency and memory usage between Firefox and the rest is a Gecko vs Webkit Issue. I know that the answer can be found by diving into those code bases, but I'd definitely like to know if anyone else can explain relevant details about the implementation of localStorage on these two engines to explain the massive difference in efficiency and latency across browsers?

Unfortunately, I doubt we'll be able to get to solving it, but the closer one can get is at least understanding the limitations of the browser in its current state.

Thanks!

Comment: would you mind showing what code you were using? In my load tests I got much higher speeds than that, but I never measured the underlying size of the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Browser and version becomes a major issue here. The thing is, while there are so-called "Webkit-Based" browsers, they add their own patches as well. Sometimes they make it into the main Webkit repository, sometimes they do not. With regards to versions, browsers are always moving targets, so this benchmark could be completely different if you use a beta or nightly build.

Then there is overall use case. If your use case is not the norm, the issues will not be as apparent, and it's less likely to get noticed and adressed. Even if there are patches, browser vendors have a lot of issues to address, so there a chance it's set for another build (again, nightly builds might produce different results).

Honestly the best course of action would to be to discuss these results on the appropriate browser mailing list / forum if it hasn't been addressed already. People will be more likely to do testing and see if the results match.